# Is there a way to delete duplicates from a table with a single column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a possible way to delete duplicate rows from a table like this without dropping the table and re-creating it with distinct rows?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp (id INT);

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES (1), (2), (2), (2), (3), (3);
```

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a CTE and ROW_NUMBER grouped by the specified column you are looking at can cleanly remove duplicate values, as ROW_NUMBER counts incrementally with duplicate values of the PARTITION BY aggregation. When a new grouping is found when ordered, it resets the ROW_NUMBER to 1 starting at that next record of different grouped values.

```
 WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS RN
 FROM #temp
 )

 DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, First we have to find all recodes

```
DELETE t 
FROM #temp t 
WHERE (SELECT count(1) 
    FROM #temp t1 
    WHERE t.id =t1.id )
    >1
```

Hope you will find the best solutions.